# Change record values in Haskell

Tags: haskell, record

I am trying to write a Haskell module with the following code:

```
module RectangleMover where

data Rectangle = Rectangle { xCoordinate :: Int
                           , yCoordinate :: Int
                           , width :: Int
                           , height :: Int
                           } deriving (Show)

move :: Rectangle -> Int -> Int -> Rectangle
-- Edit 1
move rec x y =
    let rec' = { xCoordinate + x
               , yCoordinate + y
               }
    return rec
```

To create a rectangle i would type:

```
let rec = Rectangle 10 10 20 30
```

But my question is now how to implement a function that "moves" this rectangle?
In C# or Java the call would be something like this: `rec.move(20,20);`
But how would this be written in Haskell?

This is unfortunately my first try with a functional programming language...

**Edit 1:**
I added the code inside my function but still get a parse error at "xCoordinate + x" ...

Comment: What is the meaning of the two `Int` that `move` takes as parameters? Offsets along the x-axis and y-axis? Something else?

Comment: Yes the offsets of x- and y-axis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just add the offsets to the corner:

```
move :: Rectangle -> Int -> Int -> Rectangle
move (Rectangle x y w h) dx dy = Rectangle (x + dx) (y + dy) w h
```

With record syntax, though, you can write it as

```
move :: Rectangle -> Int -> Int -> Rectangle
move r@(Rectangle {xCoordinate = x, yCoordinate=y}) dx dy = r {
  xCoordinate = x + dx,
  yCoordinate = y + dy }
```

Longer, but only because of the long names chosen for the two fields to update. You might further define a `Point` type:

```
data Point = Point Int Int
movePoint :: Point -> Int -> Int -> Point
movePoint (Point x y) dx dy = Point (x + dx) (y + dy)

data Rectangle = Rectangle { corner :: Point, width :: Int, height :: Int }
move :: Rectangle -> Int -> Int -> Rectangle
move r@(Rectangle {corner=c}) dx dy = r { corner = movePoint c dx dy }
```

Comment: When i try the version with the "Point" i get `error: Not in scope: type variable ‘x’` in first line ...

Comment: i changed it to `data Point = Point { x :: Int, y :: Int }` and then `Duplicate type signatures for ‘move’ ` appeared. So i renamed the first move function to `movePoint` and now i get `Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
                  with actual type ‘Point -> Int’
`
`

Comment: Sorry about that; trygub has fixed it. I was undecided about whether to use record syntax for the `Point` type, and would up writing a broken mix of record and non-record syntax.

Answer (score 14):

Given that this is your first time with Haskell, go with the record update answer already mentioned. However, for people googling this in the future, and for you too if you are feeling more ambitious (or for future learning), Haskell has this very popular and extremely powerful library called [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

Here's how you can engineer a solution to your problem using it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

data Rectangle = Rectangle { _xCoordinate :: Int
                           , _yCoordinate :: Int
                           , _width :: Int
                           , _height :: Int
                           } deriving (Show)
makeLenses ''Rectangle

move :: Rectangle -> Int -> Int -> Rectangle
move rect dx dy= rect
                   & xCoordinate +~ dx
                   & yCoordinate +~ dy
```

This solution may not seem more powerful initially, but when you start trying to update nested records, I assure you the advantage becomes clear.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell values are immutable, so you want to return a new `Rectangle` with the desired properties modified. It's simple, use "Record Update Syntax" like this `let myNewRec = rec { yCoordinate = 20, xCoordinate = 20 }`

Comment: But can i use this syntax also inside my "move" function block? Or how would this be written?As you said I need to create a new rectangle and return this new rectangle from the "move" function, right?

Comment: I changed my code above (Edit 1), but i still get a parse error at "xCoordinate + x"

Comment: `move :: Rectangle -> Int -> Int -> Rectangle`  and `move rec x y = rec { xCoodinate = x , yCoodinate = y }`.  You could do this without the record names too: `move (Record _ _ w h) x y = Record x y w h`.